# Perl "Opening multiple csv files" + "Pulling part of their name and storing it"

Tags: perl, csv

I know right this title makes no sense!

I've started coding Perl a few days ago so don't judge me.

I've got multiple CSV files with names that are partially identical. A few example names:

```
Belgroep\ 00.csv, Belgroep\ 01.csv, Belgroep\ 02.csv
```

so my script has too loop through all the files starting at 00 at ends at 46
Then it has to get the numbers from the name and store them in a variable.

Would be great if you guys could tell me which modules methods etc, to use when attempting to make this script with my limited knowledge.

Comment: `Text::CSV` would be a good choice.

Comment: *"so my script has too loop throught all the files starting at 00 at ends at 46 Then it has to get the numbers from the name and store them in a variable."*  Please clarify this.  Do you file names range from `00.csv` .. `46.csv`?  If so, why do you need to read the dir?  Also, don't you already have the numbers if the files have that name range?  What do you plan to do with the names?  Do yo need to `open` any of the files?

Comment: So my files are called Belgroep\ 00.csv (\space becouse i'm in linux) and their's 46 of them and i've gotta read all of them get certain rows from them at the same time it has to read the last 2 characters of the file name wich is 00 till 46 and then put it in a row in the new CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code to get you started:

```
# Test files created in linux via:
# touch Belgroep\ {00..46}.csv 

my $CWD = '.';

# Get a handle for the current working directory:
opendir MYDIR, $CWD;


while( readdir MYDIR ){

  print "Processing file: $CWD/$_\n";

  if ( "$_" =~ m/[0-9]{2}/ ) {  # this file name has a number pair in it.
    my $file = $_;
    my ($num) = $_ =~ /([\d]{2})/;
    print "Number for file \"$file\" is $num\n";
  }
}
```

Using the perldoc command with the -f option to give you details on each of the functions.

For example:  perldoc -f opendir

The [Learn Perl website](http://learn.perl.org/) is also a great resource.

For modules, you should search [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/)